# How to use adb shell command to launch the app with same package id but different application id

Tags: android, adb, android-shell

I have 2 variants of the same app installed on my Android device which have the same package id but different application id. I am not able to launch the application using the shell command whose application id is different than the package id.

I am aware of the following command to launch app

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Comment: is the answer below helping to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply invoke

```
adb shell am start -n first-application-id/common-package-name.ActivityName
```

and

```
adb shell am start -n second-application-id/common-package-name.ActivityName
```